# Infinite scroll на элементах

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть страница, на которую выводятся порядка 40-50 блочных элементов при помощи append(), что делает страницу очень большой. Элементы отображаются по 3 штуки в ряд. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при загрузке страницы отображались лишь первые 9 элементов, а остальные начинали отображаться при прокрутке вниз или по нажатию на кнопку "Показать больше". Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой скрипт можно для этого использовать. Поиски ничего не дали.

Comment: [`Intersection Observer API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)?

Comment: @Other у него статус совместимости Editor's Draft, а мне совместимость важна во всех браузерах.

Comment: А `babel` на что?